# How to give ffmpeg command to decode rtsp stream that has a '?' in the password?

Tags: ffmpeg, passwords, escaping

Let us say the password is 'password?'. The RTSP URL might look like this then:

`rtsp://admin:password?@192.168.1.12:554/path/to/stream.sdp`

The issue is, when I use this in a command like:

`ffmpeg -t 00:00:05 -i rtsp://admin:password?@192.168.1.12:554/path/to/stream.sdp out.mp4`

I always get an error:

```
[tcp @ 0x7fa03a700160] Port missing in uri
rtsp://admin:admin\?@192.168.1.13:554/live/0/h264.sdp: Invalid argument
```

I think it's because of the question mark, but I can't get the error to go away. I've tried surround the URI in double-quotes, single-quotes, and escaping the question-mark by `\?` but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. You need to URI-escape it, so encode it like you would for URL parameters.
so
`rtsp://admin:password?@192.168.1.33/live/0/h264.sdp` becomes
`rtsp://admin:password%3F@192.168.1.33/live/0/h264.sdp`